# Show increasing and decreasing values on noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm using a noUiSlider with one handle and a range from 0 to 50. I'm trying to show the increasing value of the slider on an input field to the left of the slider and the diminishing value on the right - as in the below example:

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UC3H.png)

Has anyone else tried to do this or know how it can be achieved?

```
var connectSlider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
start: 20,
tooltips: true,
decimals: 0,
connect: [true, false],
range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 50,
},
  format: wNumb ({decimals:0})
}); 

var inputFormat = document.getElementById('slider-value');

 sliderFormat.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
inputFormat.value = values[handle];
});

inputFormat.addEventListener('change', function(){
sliderFormat.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
$("#slider").Link('lower').to('#slider-value',function(value){
$(this).val(Math.abs(value));
});
```

Here it is in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dotwebs/wk27j7sL/13/)

I managed to get the left value to display on the screen but don't know how to bind it to the input field. And I don't know how to get the value on the right. I assume this should be 'max value' minus 'slider value' but don't have enough knowledge of JavaScript so I would really appreciate some help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with ***Slider*** control from the *0.99.0* ***Materialize*** version and I wanted to get that behavior too. So I do some tricks as follow:

**My HTML inside a form tag:**

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <label for="wmAttendance">Porcentaje de Asistencias</label><br>
    <p class="range-field">
        <input type="range" id="test5" min="0" max="100" oninput="wAttendance.value = test5.value" />
        <output id="wAttendance" name="wAttendance">0<span>% - Mujeres</span></output>
        <output id="mAttendance" name="mAttendance" class="right">0<span>% - Hombres</span></output>
    </p>
</div>
```

**JS needed to intercept changes on the range input**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test5").on("input", function() {
        var women = this.value, men = 100 - women;
        $("#a_women").html(women);
        $("#a_men").html(men);
        $("#wAttendance").html(women + "<span>% - Mujeres</span>");
        $("#mAttendance").html(men + "<span>% - Hombres</span>");
    });
});
```

And voila we have make the magic happen and the result is something like this:
[image]

In this way we can catch both values to send in the form or to make some operations etc. Here you have [**my pen**](https://codepen.io/alexventura/pen/vZrxrb) for reference.

I hope it could be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had a play with you code and got this working:

```
var connectSlider = document.getElementById('slider');

// add max amount variable (used to calculate #slider-value-after input value)
var maxAmount = 50

noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
    start: 20,
    tooltips: true,
    decimals: 0,
    connect: [true, false],
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': maxAmount, // use max amount variable to set max range amount
    },
  format: wNumb ({decimals:0})
}); 


var inputFormat = document.getElementById('slider-value');
// created variable for #slider-value-after input
var inputFormat2 = document.getElementById('slider-value-after');

// for some reason you were looking for a 'sliderFormat' variable to watch for slider updates
// this wasnt created and was causing JS errors in the fiddle 
// Ive updated this to the 'connectSlider' variable you created.
connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    // on update set first input value
    inputFormat.value = values[handle];
    // also set #slider-value-after input value by minus'ing the max value by current slider value
    inputFormat2.value = maxAmount - values[handle];
});

inputFormat.addEventListener('change', function(){
    connectSlider.noUiSlider.set(this.value);
});
```

I think it is also possible to get slider options which would remove the need to set the maxAmount variable as you could query the sliders max range amount instead but I cant remember the code for this.